# How to specify package's python version in conda install

Tags: python, package, conda

I need to install pymysql for my python3 environment, I can see

```
binstar search -t conda PyMySQL
pandas/pymysql            |    0.6.2 | conda           | linux-64        | py34_0, py33_0, py26_0, py27_0
```

That means py34_0 is available from pandas channel, however, how can I specify the python34 package? if I run

`conda install -c pandas pymysql`

it will collect and install py27 package.

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

If I follow @gdlmx, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's the default behavior. If your conda has python 3.4 then only the package for py34_0 will be installed.

Comment: Thanks. How do I tell my conda's python version? If I run `conda -V`, I got 4.6.7

Comment: Indeed, my conda is Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh from here: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html, I chose the version for Python 3.7

Comment: Then you can use the `pymysql` from the [official anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pymysql)

Comment: Not working, see update in OP. Thanks.

Comment: I just tested in my anaconda env, it successfully locate pymysql with py36, so everything seems fine. Maybe something is wrong with your environment. Can you check the python version and the conda package version by running `python --version; conda list | grep python` ?

Comment: Thanks, I think you got the point, there is no python3 in conda list - I am very surprised. `python --version ` gives me 3.4.8

Comment: That's very surprising, `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh` should install python by default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also specify the Python version if you're creating an environment

```
conda create -n myenv -c pandas python=3.4 pymysql
```

If you're installing into an existing environment, you need to make sure the appropriate version of Python is installed into that environment.

Comment: Thanks. The env has python3: `which python3
~/venv/bin/python3`

Comment: Venv and conda don't mix. Why are you trying to mix them? Just use conda envronments.